# iOS Saving Captured Images to memory and accessing them

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to develop an iOS application that captures an image with an iPhone camera and saves that image to the camera roll (or just somewhere I can access it for later).  I was looking into different ways to do that but I got stuck.  I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction regarding how to do this.  Here is the code that I have currently:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Camera: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var Camera: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var PhotoLibrary: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageDisplay: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func PhotoLibraryAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)

}

@IBAction func CameraAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }



func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    ImageDisplay.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage;
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Basically what I have right now is a system that allows the user to press a button that will then start the camera.  Once the camera is started the user can use the camera like normal to take a picture. Once the picture is taken, it takes the user back to the original screen.  The problem that I'm facing is that I'm fairly certain after the user reaches that point, the picture the user just took still isn't stored to the device, meaning that I can't access it later in the future.  Additionally I was hoping someone could explain to me the best way to access the picture once it's been saved to the camera roll.  I know there are ways to access it via the picture name, but how would I know what the photo will be called?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you put a break point here `imagePickerController ` or a print in order in order to check info dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do any saving in your code, you need to save your image to photo album, add this line before 'dismissViewControllerAnimated'

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(ImageDisplay.image,nil,nil,nil)
```

Comment: You are amazing.  Thank you so much!  I do have one other question, what is, in your opinion, the best way to access the new photo?  Is there a way I can grab the photo's name and then access it with its name?

Comment: This code will just save your image in iOS Photo library without any identifier to retrieve exact same photo, so to access it again you have to force user to open imagePickerController again and manually select it. To get more control over saved image you can use ALAsset/PHAsset class, but the code will be more complicated.